# Proof or disproof (by a counter example) of A×B⊆C×D if and only if A⊆C and B⊆D

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question: Prove or disprove (by giving a counterexample) that A×B⊆C×D if and only if A⊆C and B⊆D

I felt the statement would be true. 
So I tried to prove that A×B⊆C×D ⇔ A⊆C∧B⊆D

A×B⊆C×D

⇔[(a, b)∈A×B⇒(a, b)∈C×D] by def. of ⊆

⇔[(a∈A∧b∈B)⇒(a∈C∧b∈D)] by  def. of Cartesian product

⇔ ~(a∈A∧b∈B)∨(a∈C∧b∈D) by  def. of conditional($→$), De Morgan's Laws.

⇔ (a∉A∨b∉B)∨(a∈C∧b∈D)  by  notaion of negation

⇔ (a∉A∨**b∉B**∨a∈C)∧(**a∉A**∨b∉B∨b∈D) by distributive law of logic

Then I felt that I should remove b∉B in the left bracket and a∉A in the right bracket because 
[(a∉A∨a∈C)∧(b∉B∨b∈D)]⇔[(a∈A⇒a∈C)∧(b∈B⇒b∈D)]by the definition of conditional⇔[a∈(A⊆C)∧b∈(B⊆D)] by the definition of subset(⊆)

Then back to 
(a∉A∨**b∉B**∨a∈C)∧(**a∉A**∨b∉B∨b∈D) by distributive law of logic

⇔ [(a∉A∨**b∉B**∨a∈C)∧a∉A]∨[(a∉A∨a∈C∨**b∉B**)∧(b∉B∨b∈D)] by distributive law of logic, commutative laws of logic

Now from here I don't know if I can reach the result because if I keep applying distributive law of logic and commutative laws of logic like this, the left bracket seems to become more complex rather than removing , and so would be the right bracket.

[(a∉A∨b∉B∨a∈C)∧**a∉A**]⇔[(a∉A∧a∉A)∨((b∉B∨a∈C)∧a∉A)] by distributive law
⇔[a∉A∨((b∉B∨a∈C)∧a∉A)] by laws of Idempotency

But I don't know what counterexample should I give to disprove. Nor I know how to further develop the logical step. Can you solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implication $$A \subseteq C\text{ and }B \subseteq D \implies A \times B \subseteq C \times D$$ is trivial.

The converse is false if $A$ or $B$ is allowed to be empty: let $A = \{a,b\}$, $C = \{c\}$, and $B = D = \emptyset$, then $A \not\subseteq C$ but $\emptyset = A \times B \subseteq C \times D = \emptyset$.

Now suppose that $A$ and $B$ are non-empty and that $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$. Let $a \in A$. Since $B$ is non-empty, there is a $b \in B$, and so $(a,b) \in A \times B \subseteq C \times D$, that is to say $a \in C$. Thus $A \subseteq C$. A symmetric argument shows that $B \subseteq D$ because $A$ is non-empty.

---

As requested, to write the above argument in harder-to-read form: we will show that $(A \times B \subseteq C \times D) \wedge (B \neq \emptyset) \implies A \subseteq C$. Indeed we have
$$\begin{align*}
(A \times B \subseteq C \times D) \wedge (B \neq \emptyset) &\implies \forall a \in A, \exists b \in B : (A \times B \subseteq C \times D) \wedge (a,b) \in A \times B\\
&\implies \forall a \in A, \exists b \in B : (a,b) \in C \times D\\
&\implies \forall a \in A: a \in C\\
&\iff A \subseteq C.\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I don't know how $$A \subseteq C\text{ and }B \subseteq D \implies A \times B \subseteq C \times D$$ is proved. But It's a useful finding that Ø×A=Ø, Ø×A=Ø can be used to disprove the statement.

Comment: @buzzee It's proved straight from the definitions. To prove $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$ you need to show that an element $(a,b) \in A \times B$ belongs to $C \times D$, i.e., that $a \in A$ belongs to $C$ and that $b \in B$ belongs to $D$. But this is precisely what the hypothesis $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$ gives us.

Comment: The direction you trying to prove is A×B⊆C×D ⇒ A⊆C.                        So B⊆D A×B⊆C×D 
⇔[(a,b)∈A×B ⇒ (a,b)∈C×D]
⇔[a∈A∧b∈B ⇒ a∈C∧b∈D] 
⇔[a∈A∧b∈B ⇒ a∈C∧b∈D] 
but we can't deduce from this logical step that A⊆C and B⊆D.
That's how I tried at first. 


(a,b)∈A×B ⇒ (a,b)∈C×D

Comment: @buzzee See my edit.

Comment: You wrote that the implication $$A \subseteq C\text{ and }B \subseteq D \implies A \times B \subseteq C \times D$$ is trivial.

So why do you show  $(A \times B \subseteq C \times D) \wedge (B \neq \emptyset) \implies A \subseteq C$? $$A \subseteq C\text{ and }B \subseteq D \implies A \times B \subseteq C \times D$$ and  $(A \times B \subseteq C \times D) \wedge (B \neq \emptyset) \implies A \subseteq C$ are two different statements.

Comment: @buzzee You asked for clarification on the non-trivial implication: "The direction you trying to prove is A×B⊆C×D ⇒ A⊆C..."

Comment: Oh I checked my comment above and found that there's a part I missed writing. I wish I could edit my second comment. "A×B⊆C×D ⇒ A⊆C" was not my question, I was trying to mention that the direction you were trying to prove is 'A×B⊆C×D ⇒ A⊆C∧B⊆D' since you have A×B⊆C×D as a premise(hypothesis) by supposing it in the answer box, in contrast to the hypothesis A⊆C and B⊆D you wrote in "A⊆C and B⊆D⇒A×B⊆C×D ".

Answer (score 3):

Given that $A,B,C,D$ are all *nonempty* sets, the statement is in fact true.

**However**, there is a counterexample to the general case, and that is when you allow some of the sets to be empty.

Note that $\emptyset \times F=\emptyset$ for any set $F$.

As a result, when $A\supsetneq C$ and $B=D=\emptyset$ you have $\emptyset=A\times B\subseteq C\times D=\emptyset$ despite $A\not\subseteq C$

Comment: But that's not a counterexample. A⊆C is the same as C ⊆A. It can't be $A\not\subseteq C$

Comment: @buzzee: No, $A\subseteq C$ is *not* the same as $C\subseteq A.$

Comment: @buzzee The definition of $A\subseteq C$ is $x\in A\Rightarrow x\in C$ For example $A=\{1,2\}$ and $C=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  Here we have regardless which number from $A$ you pick ($1$ or $2$), it is also in $C$.  However $C\not\subseteq A$ in my example because there are elements in $C$ which are not in $A$ (namely $3,4,$ and $5$).  The subset relation $\subseteq$ is a *partial order* which is in particular **anti-symmetric**.  (the only way that $A\subseteq C$ and $C\subseteq A$ at the same time is if $A=C$)

Comment: Oh I checked the definition of a subset again. (A⊆C)≡∀x(x∈A⇒x∈C),
(C⊆A)≡∀x(x∈C⇒x∈A)  Ah my mistake. I was mixing them up.